# iPhone:Cookie to accept and send back to server - ASIHttpRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using the following ASIHttpRequest api to do some authentication stuff.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:path]] autorelease];
```

I'm trying to accept the cookies comes from server in this URL and send them back to server to maintain the session on server. Please advise, how can i achieve this? I tried reading the below link,
[ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#cookies)
But it doesn't mention anything like how can an iPhone app code receive session cookie data from server and accept and send them back to server to maintain the session.

Could someone please guide me on this.

Thank you!

**UPDATED:**
Can i use the following code to read and get the cookies?

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *sharedHTTPCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]; 
    //NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy currentPolicy = [sharedHTTPCookieStorage cookieAcceptPolicy];
    [sharedHTTPCookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy: NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
    NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];

    NSLog(@"cookie count: %i", [cookies count]);
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cookies objectEnumerator];
    NSString *value;
    while ( cookie = [enumerator nextObject] )
    {
        value = [cookie value];
    }
```

Comment: The documentation suggests that `ASIHTTPRequest`, just as `NSURLRequest`, handles receiving and sending cookies automatically for you.

Comment: Ok, how can i make sure that the receiving cookie is what server really sent?

Comment: You could read the cookies that are set with `[[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"]`

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I updated a code snippet in my question. Please check and update me can i use that code to get the cookies? Or it needs to modify anything?